# Json editor wanted for angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am working on angular 2 with typescript and wondering if there is a workable jsoneditor like this https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor for angular2?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you just use that one? As in, why would you need an angular2 jsoneditor, if you could write a `d.ts` file for this one, and just use it in typescript :)

Comment: thanks for the kindly reply

Comment: @BobZhang I find myself in the same position you were in; did you write a ts file for https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor that you'd be willing to share?

Comment: This could help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/json-editor

Comment: https://github.com/Urbansson/ng2-jsoneditor/issues/3#issuecomment-277907043  try this. I found a simple workaround for the issue