# Angular: Show list in view with different object keys

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object

I have the following JSON object:

```
header: {
        first: {
            title: {
                name: "Test
            }
        },
        second: {
            title: {
                name: "Test 2"
            },
            desc: {
                name: "Description"
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to show it in view like that:
[image]

How can I manage to do that in the view? Since the keys will vary every time. For example once you have `header`, another time `main` and so on... Something like JSONEditor, where you can edit JSON objects. But I want to create something like that with my own design. I tried with ngIf but it seems really difficult. I'd be really thankful for any suggestions or help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849812/json-editor-wanted-for-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate over objects using `ngFor`.

```
<!-- app-your-node component -->
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{ title }}
  <app-your-leaf *ngIf="yourLogicThatThisIsALeaf(item); else node" 
                 [title]="item.key" [object]="item.value"><app-your-leaf>
  <ng-template #node>
    <app-your-node [title]="item.key" [object]="item.value"></app-your-node>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```